# Does "which" here mean "that"?

Tags: meaning

Does ***which*** here mean ***that***?

> On the other hand, it is only fair to add that the Mr. Bell who occupied
>   the house at that time was not a man of notorious character, and one
>   would willingly concede that an accusation founded entirely upon
>   psychic evidence would be an unfair and intolerable thing. It is very
>   different, however, when the proofs of a crime have actually been
>   discovered, and the evidence then centres merely upon ***which*** tenant
>   was in possession at that particular time. The deposition of Lucretia
>   Pulver assumes vital importance in its bearing upon this matter.

Comment: Imagine "the question of" inserted before "which".

Answer (score 2):

No, it doesn't.

The sentence is stating that the evidence centres on WHO the tenant was at the time.

**Which tenant** is used here as an adjective in the sense of **which one was it**.

It's the same sense as in: **I'm deciding which coat I should wear.**

The sentence would not read correctly if written as: **...centres on THAT tenant was in possession...** unless one inserted **who** after tenant.

http://partofspeech.org/what-part-of-speech-is-which/

Comment: It's effectively the "question word" which. You could restate the phrase as "the evidence then centres merely upon **the question of** which tenant was in possession at that particular time" (but it's unnecessary, which is why they omitted it).